# Primefaces steps skip validation on primefaces file uploader

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I have several (5) primefaces steps.  All of my form items validate pretty well, but my primefaces file uploader is not validated:

```
                    <p:fileUpload
                            fileUploadListener="#{cc.attrs.bean.handler}"
                            mode="simple"
                            immediate="true"
                            required="true" requiredMessage="#{i18n.requiredUploaderMessage}" auto="true"
                            label="#{i18n.UploadMessageDefault}" skinSimple="true"
                            id="file-termo-adesao" sizeLimit="2000000" fileLimit="1"
                            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf|doc|docx|odt)$/">
                    </p:fileUpload>
```

Is it possible to validate file uploader inside steps, like the other form elements?

Comment: I think it is because file upload uses its own AJAX calls outside of normal PF calls when its doing its uploads etc.  So its not running through normal validations.  If I remember there are some JS tricks you can do if you search around.

Comment: What kind of validation do you need? Which Pf version are you using? Do you have others fileUpload in the same form?

Comment: @Melloware I'm trying to figure out how can I fix this

Comment: @MatteoZanini Primefaces 6.2 / Just one fileUploader